# Split page into 4 equal sections with fixed header

Tags: css

I am trying to divide a page into 4 equal sections (2x2 grid) with a fixed header. So far I have a it split into 4 but because of the header, the page is going bigger than 100%.

I want the 4 parts to only take up the available space on the screen and not make the page scroll but be equal.

HTML:

```
<header></header>

<div class="container">
    <div class="block blue"></div>
    <div class="block green"></div>
    <div class="block purple"></div>
    <div class="block red"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 117px;
     background-color: grey;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.block {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.blue {
    border-top: 4px solid blue; 
}  

.green {
    border-top: 4px solid green;
}

.purple {
    border-top: 4px solid purple;
}

.red {
    border-top: 4px solid red;
}
```

See demo so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Kas78/1/

I also want to be able to make it responsive so that each block can be changed to 100% width and a fixed height when the page is smaller than 690px so that needs to be kept in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recomment to change your code to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/Kas78/2/

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

header {
    height: 117px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.container {
    height: calc(100% - 117px);
}

.block {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

I throw out some `width:100%` since block elements will fill the parent element by default.

Comment: Do IE8 and IE9 support the calc function? I assume all modern browsers will